# How to generate pdf server side using Crystal Reports with C# / ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, file, pdf, crystal-reports, itext

I need to generate some reports in a system that I am developing...

Right Now I have a sample using itext sharp... however, due to it's simplicity, I can't create good looking reports...

So I was asked to switch to Crystal Reports, however I have no clue where or how to begin...

From the tutorials I have saw, it seems that the user can create his own reports using CR tools, but what I Want is that the report generates automatically taking some data that the user provides...

Here's a sample of what I did with iText sharp

```
public class GeneracionPDF
{
    //I need a list for products and a list for services
    List<Producto> listaProductos = new List<Producto>();
    List<Servicio> listaServicios = new List<Servicio>();

    private Producto objProducto = new Producto();
    private Servicio objServicio = new Servicio();
    private CarritoVenta objCV = new CarritoVenta();

    public void GenerarPdf(List<Articulo> lstArticulos, string strNombreReporte, string strEmpresa, string strSlogan, string strNombreVendedor, string strNombreCliente, string strRuta)
    {
        Organizar(lstArticulos);

        #region Inicio
        Document documento = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 50, 50, 50, 50);
        PdfWriter writerPdf = PdfWriter.GetInstance(documento, new FileStream(strRuta + strNombreReporte, FileMode.Create));
        documento.Open();
        #endregion

        #region Titulo
        Font font1 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 18, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLUE);
        Phrase phrEmpresa = new Phrase(strEmpresa + "\n", font1);

        Font font2 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 12, Font.ITALIC, BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
        Phrase phrSlogan = new Phrase(strSlogan, font2);

        Font font16I = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 16, Font.ITALIC, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Phrase phrDescrip = new Phrase(("Cliente: " + strNombreCliente), font16I);

        PdfContentByte cb = writerPdf.DirectContent;
        documento.Add(phrEmpresa);
        documento.Add(phrSlogan);
        documento.Add(phrDescrip);
        BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
        Font fontHelvetica16red = new Font(bfTimes, 12, Font.ITALIC, BaseColor.RED);
        #endregion

        #region Seccion Productos
        if (listaProductos.Count > 0)
        {
            documento.Add(new Paragraph("\n Productos \n", fontHelvetica16red));
            PdfPTable tableProductos = null;

            tableProductos = new PdfPTable(6);
            float[] colWidths = { 100, 200, 400, 150, 150, 150 };
            tableProductos.SetWidths(colWidths);
            Font LetraTituloTabla = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 10, Font.NORMAL);
            Font LetraCeldaTabla = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8, Font.NORMAL);

            PdfPCell celdaIdProducto = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("ID", LetraTituloTabla));
            PdfPCell celdaNombreProducto = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Nombre", LetraTituloTabla));
            PdfPCell celdaDescripcionProducto = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Descripción", LetraTituloTabla));
            PdfPCell celdaPrecioProducto = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Precio", LetraTituloTabla));
            PdfPCell celdaCantidadProducto = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cantidad", LetraTituloTabla));
            PdfPCell celdaTotalProducto = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Total", LetraTituloTabla));

            celdaIdProducto.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            celdaNombreProducto.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            celdaDescripcionProducto.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            celdaPrecioProducto.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            celdaCantidadProducto.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            celdaTotalProducto.HorizontalAlignment = 1;

            tableProductos.AddCell(celdaIdProducto);
            tableProductos.AddCell(celdaNombreProducto);
            tableProductos.AddCell(celdaDescripcionProducto);
            tableProductos.AddCell(celdaPrecioProducto);
            tableProductos.AddCell(celdaCantidadProducto);
            tableProductos.AddCell(celdaTotalProducto);

            foreach (Producto prod in listaProductos)
            {
                celdaIdProducto = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(prod.IdProducto.ToString(), LetraCeldaTabla));
                celdaNombreProducto = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(prod.Nombre, LetraCeldaTabla));
                celdaDescripcionProducto = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(prod.Descripcion, LetraCeldaTabla));
                celdaPrecioProducto = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("$ " + prod.PrecioVenta, LetraCeldaTabla));
                celdaCantidadProducto = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(prod.Cantidad.ToString(), LetraCeldaTabla));
                celdaTotalProducto = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("$ " + prod.TotalCompra, LetraCeldaTabla));

                celdaIdProducto.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                celdaNombreProducto.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                celdaDescripcionProducto.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                celdaPrecioProducto.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                celdaCantidadProducto.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                celdaTotalProducto.HorizontalAlignment = 1;

                tableProductos.AddCell(celdaIdProducto);
                tableProductos.AddCell(celdaNombreProducto);
                tableProductos.AddCell(celdaDescripcionProducto);
                tableProductos.AddCell(celdaPrecioProducto);
                tableProductos.AddCell(celdaCantidadProducto);
                tableProductos.AddCell(celdaTotalProducto);
            }

            documento.Add(tableProductos);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Seccion Servicios
        if (listaServicios.Count > 0)
        {
            documento.Add(new Paragraph("\n Servicios \n", fontHelvetica16red));
            PdfPTable tableServicios = null;

            tableServicios = new PdfPTable(6);
            float[] colWidths = { 100, 200, 400, 150, 150, 150 };
            tableServicios.SetWidths(colWidths);
            Font LetraTituloTabla = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 10, Font.NORMAL);
            Font LetraCeldaTabla = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 8, Font.NORMAL);

            PdfPCell celdaIdServicio = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("ID", LetraTituloTabla));
            PdfPCell celdaNombreServicio = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Nombre", LetraTituloTabla));
            PdfPCell celdaDescripcionServicio = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Descripción", LetraTituloTabla));
            PdfPCell celdaPrecioServicio = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Precio", LetraTituloTabla));
            PdfPCell celdaCantidadServicio = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cantidad", LetraTituloTabla));
            PdfPCell celdaTotalServicio = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Total", LetraTituloTabla));

            celdaIdServicio.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            celdaNombreServicio.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            celdaDescripcionServicio.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            celdaPrecioServicio.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            celdaCantidadServicio.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            celdaTotalServicio.HorizontalAlignment = 1;

            tableServicios.AddCell(celdaIdServicio);
            tableServicios.AddCell(celdaNombreServicio);
            tableServicios.AddCell(celdaDescripcionServicio);
            tableServicios.AddCell(celdaPrecioServicio);
            tableServicios.AddCell(celdaCantidadServicio);
            tableServicios.AddCell(celdaTotalServicio);

            foreach (Servicio ser in listaServicios)
            {
                celdaIdServicio = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(ser.IdServicio.ToString(), LetraCeldaTabla));
                celdaNombreServicio = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(ser.Nombre, LetraCeldaTabla));
                celdaDescripcionServicio = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(ser.Descripcion, LetraCeldaTabla));
                celdaPrecioServicio = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("$ " + ser.Precio, LetraCeldaTabla));
                celdaCantidadServicio = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(ser.Cantidad.ToString(), LetraCeldaTabla));
                celdaTotalServicio = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("$ " + ser.Total, LetraCeldaTabla));

                celdaIdServicio.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                celdaNombreServicio.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                celdaDescripcionServicio.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                celdaPrecioServicio.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                celdaCantidadServicio.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                celdaTotalServicio.HorizontalAlignment = 1;

                tableServicios.AddCell(celdaIdServicio);
                tableServicios.AddCell(celdaNombreServicio);
                tableServicios.AddCell(celdaDescripcionServicio);
                tableServicios.AddCell(celdaPrecioServicio);
                tableServicios.AddCell(celdaCantidadServicio);
                tableServicios.AddCell(celdaTotalServicio);
            }

            documento.Add(tableServicios);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Finalizacion
        //This method returns a decimal value, so no worries here
        decimal decSubtotal = objCV.Subtotal(lstArticulos);

        documento.Add(new Paragraph("\n Subtotal: $" + decSubtotal, fontHelvetica16red));
        documento.Add(new Paragraph("IVA: $" + (decSubtotal * 0.11m), fontHelvetica16red));
        documento.Add(new Paragraph("Total: $" + (decSubtotal * 1.11m), fontHelvetica16red));
        documento.Add(new Paragraph("\nNota: Si no requiere factura, omita el IVA", fontHelvetica16red));
        documento.Close();
        #endregion
    }

    //Method to separate products and services in different lists, since lstArticulos contains both products and services
    private void Organizar(List<Articulo> lstArticulos)
    {
        listaProductos.Clear();
        listaServicios.Clear();

        foreach (Articulo art in lstArticulos)
        {
            if (art.Tipo == "Producto")
            {
                objProducto = new Producto(int.Parse(art.IdArticulo.Substring(8)), art.Nombre, art.Descripcion, art.Imagen, art.Precio, art.Cantidad);
                listaProductos.Add(objProducto);
            }

            else if (art.Tipo == "Servicio")
            {
                objServicio = new Servicio(int.Parse(art.IdArticulo.Substring(8)), art.Nombre, art.Descripcion, art.Imagen, art.Precio, art.Cantidad);
                listaServicios.Add(objServicio);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So just like I create pdf's on server side like in the previous example, I would like to do the same but with Crystal Reports...

Is there a way I can do something similar?? any tutorials??
oh and BTW... how can I insert images on the pdf?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

here a tutorial in order to create dynamically your crystal report column

```
http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-dynamic-crystal-reports.htm
```

But it will be better:

1. if you use crystal report make template that your user will fill because beautiful rendering are possible only with crystal report wizard (and don't let too freedom in making report)
2. Prefer use SSRS (Sql server Reporting Service) it is better for performance and management of report (you have a web server by default and you can use webservice to manage template report)